# How to evaluate the volume of tetrahedron bounded between coordinate planes and tangent plane?

Tags: integration, 3d, volume

Find the volume of the tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$ bounded by the coordinate planes $x =0, y=0, z=0$, and the
tangent plane at the point $(4,5,5)$ to the sphere $(x -3)^2 +(y -3)^2 +(z -3)^2 = 9$.

My attempt: I started with determining the equation of tangent plane which comes out to be $x+2y+2z=24$. This is because direction ratios of normal to sphere at $(4, 5, 5)$ are $2, 4, 4$. So, then equation of tangent plant is given by $2(x-4)+4(y-5)+4(z-5)=0$ which means $x+2y+2z=24$.

The required volume is $$\int _{x=0}^4\int _{y=0}^{12-\frac{x}{2}}\int _{z=0}^{12-y-\frac{x}{2}}\:\:dz\:dy\:dx$$ but this is not giving me the required answer which is $576$. Please help.

Comment: $x$ should go from $0$ to $24$. Also, oddly enough, your work is correct even though you've written down the wrong plane twice.

Comment: You don't integration to calculate the volume of a third base times height.

Comment: @Ninad Munshi  yes noted.

Comment: You don't need an integration, just do $abc/6$, where $a,b,c$ are the intercepts of the plane on the axes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work seems fine, there is only an issue for the $x$ upper limit

$$V=\int _{x=0}^{24}\int _{y=0}^{12-\frac{x}{2}}\int _{z=0}^{12-y-\frac{x}{2}}\:\:dz\:dy\:dx$$

As noticed in the comments, to check the result we can use that

$$V=\frac13 Sh$$

which in this case leads to

$$V=\frac13 144 \cdot 12=576$$

Answer (score 3):

The plane intercept the axes in the points
\begin{align}
A&=(24,0,0), \\
B&=(0,12,0), \\
C&=(0,0,12)
\end{align}
so the volume is
$$
V=\frac{1}{6}\cdot24\cdot12\cdot12=576
$$

Comment: Your answer was very helpful! Can you please tell me how can we find the plane intercepts in general?

Comment: @USER0117: write the equation of the plane, then substitute $(x_1,0,0),$ $(0,y_1,0),$ $(0,0,z_1)$ in turn to find $x_1, y_1, z_1.$ The equation of the plane is $a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0),$ where $(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(4,5,5)$ and $(a,b,c)$ is the normal vector to the plane and to the sphere, found as gradient of the sphere in $(4,5,5).$

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I got it!